# Map of tangent spaces is the Jacobian in Algebraic Geometry

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I need your collected brainpower to help me out. This is going to be long, so grab your favorite beverage and snack. I am working through Görtz and Wedhorn's "Algebraic Geometry I"  and I am currently at chapter 6, more specifically the tangent space definition. So they are giving the "usual" definition of the tangent space of a scheme $X$ at a point $x$ by

$$ T_xX:=(\mathfrak{m}_x/\mathfrak{m}_x^2)^*. $$

Now let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism of schemes, than we have a map $f_x^\sharp:\mathcal{O}_{Y,f(x)}\to \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ which induces a $k(x)$-linear map from $\mathfrak{m}_{f(x)}/\mathfrak{m}_{f(x)}^2\otimes_{k(f(x))}k(x) \to \mathfrak{m}_x/\mathfrak{m}_x^2$. Dualizing this map gives us a map on tangent spaces which we denote:

$$ df:T_xX \to T_{f(x)}Y\otimes_{k(f(x))}k(x). $$

For those of you who have the book in front of you: I'm now particularly interested in Example 6.4 and there especially the second part which is as following: Let $\mathbb{A}^n_k$ be the affine space over a field $k$. Here the authors don't make any restriction on the field. This is going to be important to my question.

Now let $f:\mathbb{A}^n\to \mathbb{A}^r$ be a map given by polynomials $f_1,\ldots,f_r \in k[T_1,\ldots,T_n]$ and let $x\in \mathbb{A}^n_k(k)$ be a rational point. Then the map $df_x$ is given by the Jacobian:

$$ \left( \dfrac{\partial f_i}{\partial T_j} \right)_{i,j}. $$

Here is my attempt to confirm this: first of all I think the authors secretly assume that $k$ is algebraicly closed because they assume that $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and the associated maximal ideal is $(T_1-x_1,\ldots,T_n-x_n)$. Now let's assume this and look how the maps work. The induced map on the coordinate rings is

\begin{eqnarray}
f^\sharp:k[Y_1,\ldots,Y_r] &\to & k[T_1,\ldots,T_n]\\
g &\mapsto & g(f_1,\ldots,f_r),
\end{eqnarray}
(I hope the notation is clear). Now going to the stalks is just localizing at the respective maximal ideals which are $(T_1-x_1,\ldots,T_n-x_n)=:\mathfrak{m}_x$ and $(Y_1-b_1,\ldots,Y_r-b_r)=:\mathfrak{m}_{f(x)}$ where $b=f(x)$. I will abuse notation a little bit here, so $\mathfrak{m}_x,\mathfrak{m}_{f(x)}$ will also denote the maximal ideals in the stalk. I think this is justified since they really are the maximal ideals under the injection given by localization.

Now the induced map on the stalk level doesn't look different from the map on the coordinate rings and since we are particularly interested in how the maps work on the maximal ideals we check this for generators of $\mathfrak{m}_{f(x)}$. We can figure that the map there works as following:

\begin{eqnarray}
f^\sharp_x:\mathfrak{m}_{f(x)}&\to &\mathfrak{m}_{x}\\
Y_i-f_i(x) &\mapsto & f_i-f_i(x)
\end{eqnarray}

Now comes the interesting part and my actual question. To describe the actual map I will use the Taylor-polynomial of $f_i$ which is:

\begin{eqnarray} T_nf_i(x,T)&=&f_i(x)+\langle (gradf_{i})_x,(T-x)\rangle+\mathfrak{m}_x^2 \\
&=&f_i(x)+\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{\partial f_i}{\partial T_i}(x)(T_i-x_i)+\mathfrak{m}_x^2 .
 \end{eqnarray}
Now comes the part that bothers me: Using that $f_i(T)=T_nf_i(x,T)$ I get that $f_i-f_i(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{\partial f_i}{\partial T_i}(x)(T_i-x_i)+\mathfrak{m}_x^2 $ and so by passing to the quotient $\mathfrak{m}_x/\mathfrak{m}_x^2$ I can see how the map works and figure out that the map $df$ is indeed the Jacobian matrix.

> So here is my question: My argument relies on the identity
>
> $$ f_i(T)=T_nf_i(x,T) $$
>
> for some large enough $n$. I know that this is true for $k=\mathbb{C}$ (and therefore for any subfield) but why should this be true for any other field? In particular you have to be very carefully in even defining this in positiv characteristic. Does anybody know about this?
>
> Or alternatively: Is there another argument to see that $df$ is given by the Jacobian which doesn't involve the Taylor expansion?

Comment: I think that my answer in this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1652671/vakils-definition-of-smoothness-what-happens-at-non-closed-points/1664463#1664463 is useful. I shall wait for a your response.

Comment: @Armandoj18eos Thank's a lot for commenting! I'm not quite sure how I can use your answer though. If you look at the question I'm looking at closed points of $\mathbb{A}^n_k$. I'm aware that this method brakes down much earlier when considering non closed points. However you also seem to use a formal taylor expansion in your argument. My question is just: how is this formal taylor expansion justified. Especially in positiv characteristic you have to be carefull what you even mean by this.

Comment: Polynomials start life having Taylor expansions at $0$ and you can "center" at any other point by viewing $x-a$ as the variable. And I don't think there's any problem with picking off the linear terms using partials, since those derivatives can't be zero anyway. The higher terms are slightly worrisome but you don't need them here.

Comment: @hoot I need the higher terms in order to substitute $f_i(T)=T_nf_i(x,T)$. Or don't I? If not I would be happy if you could explain how to justify using only the linear terms in the expansion.

Comment: It just seems to me that the upshot of your Taylor stuff is that you can write $f_i(T)$ as a linear combination of monomials in the $T_j - x_j$. You need the "constant term" to be $f_i(x)$ and the coefficient of the linear term $T_j - x_j$ to be $(\partial f_i/\partial x_j)(x)$ but this can be checked.

Comment: @hoot That's precisly the point. So can you tell me how you would check this? I tried and I couldn't figure out a straight forward method.

Comment: I plug in $T = x$ to get the constant term. To get the coefficients of the linear bits I take $\partial/\partial T_j$ and plug in $T = x$ again. Some $p$-th powers in the higher order terms might become zero but so what?

Comment: @Hoot Look, i agree that we don't necessarily need the Taylor stuff. I just want to confirm that $$ f_i(T)=f_i(x)+\sum\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial T_i}(x)(T_i-x_i)+\mathfrak{m}_x^2 $$ for something in $\mathfrak{m}_x^2$ and the Taylor stuff is just a confinient way to do so. If you think this is trivial please provide an answer. Also the problem isn't so much that $p$-th powers become zero but that we divide by $p$ at some point in the formal taylor expansion. So one needs to take care of this. But I think this is not a huge problem.

Comment: I honestly believe I've outlined how to get your desired equation. I'm not claiming it's trivial to observe.

Comment: @Hoot I think it dawns on me. Need to check it after lunch. Thanks for your patience so far!

Comment: @Hoot Dear Hoot, I'm not sure if I can make sense out of your suggestion. I get your idea. If $x=0$ it works just by comparing the coefficents in the suggested way. But for $x\neq0$ a transformation $Z=T-x$ and then expanding at zero really doesn't get me anywhere. Maybe I'm missing the point, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: $k=\mathbf{C}$ should be good enough

Comment: @MaikPickl In my answer, I showed how we can describe the differential of a regular map via Jacobian matrix on any field. Formally, one can express a polynomial via its Taylor expansion, on any field. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @JuanFran I hope you are not a troll. I try to put this as politely as I can: The case $k=\mathbb{C}$ is obviously not enough for me. If you don't have to contribute anything to the question then I suggest you don't contribute at all.

Comment: @Armandoj18eos That's precisly my question. How do you express a polynomial via Taylor expansion in say positiv characteristic? And how do you show that these two things agree?

Comment: @MaikPickl why not? ever heard of the Lefschetz principle?

Comment: @JuanFran I'm sorry. I didn't meant to be rude. No I haven't heard of it. I will look into it. Thanks

Comment: @MaikPickl none taken. I also believe they assume the ground field algebraically closed.

Comment: @JuanFran just read about the principle. That's a total killer! Holy guacamole. That certainly clear's the question but still feels like shooting sparrows with a cannon.

Comment: @JuanFran And now I have to understand why the theory of algebraiclly closed fields of characteristic $p$ is complete.

Comment: @MaikPickl actually $A^n(k)=k^n$! so I am not really sure whether they assume $k$ algebraically closed!. I will think about this in more detail later. In

Comment: @JuanFran If the Taylor expansion holds for any algebraically closed field then it certainly holds for any field. Just pass to the algebraic closure and do the expansion there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to worry about whether $f_i(a)=T_nf_i(x,a)$- all you need to worry about is that this is true modulo $\mathfrak{m}_x^2$. This is easily verifiable: in positive characteristic, the difference between $f$ and $T_nf$ is a polynomial in $x^p$, so since all $p\geq 2$, we have that $f-T_nf\in \mathfrak{m}_x^2$.

Edited to add the following, from our chat:

Consider $\overline{f}$, the image of $f$ in $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}/\mathfrak{m}_x^2$. This can be written $b+\sum c_i(y_i-x_i)+\mathfrak{m}_x^2$ for $b,c_i\in\mathcal{O}_{X,x}^*$. When we take the derivative of this with respect to $y_i$, $b$ vanishes (as it is a unit), we get $c_i$ and any term in $\mathfrak{m}_x^2$ ends up in $\mathfrak{m}_x$. Passing to $\mathfrak{m}_x/\mathfrak{m}_x^2$ is equivalent to evaluating at $x$, which gives us the desired equality.

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for answering! I agree with what you are saying. But as far as I see it, that $f-T_nf \in \mathbb{m}_x^2$ is a claim of yours. You didn't proof anything.What you say is easy enough if $a=0$, but what if $a\neq 0$? Have you thought about on how to define $T_nf$ in positiv characteristic? After all you divide by $p$ for large enough $n$. I don't want to sound rude, sorry. In the comments above it was pointed out that you can use the Lefschetz principle. But I would still be interested in something elementary. If this is completely obvious to you I would be happy if you

Comment: could explain it some more.

Comment: I meant $x=0$ and $x\neq0$. Too late to edit, sorry.

Comment: I thought that $f-T_nf\in\mathfrak{m}_x^2$ was a claim you made- this comes in your post right before "Now comes the part that bothers me...". It's clear anyways- consider the image $\overline{f}$ of $f$ in the quotient $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}/\mathfrak{m}_x^2$. We can write this as $f(x)+c_i(y_i-x_i)+\mathfrak{m}_x^2$ and we have all we need once we observe that the $c_i$ are exactly the derivative in the $y_i$ direction.

Comment: You are right. I claimed that this is the case. But I was aware that I only understand this in certain situations. Can you explain to me how you observe that the $c_i$ are the partial derivatives? Also why is $f(x)-\sum c_i x_i$ the constant term of $\overline{f}$?

Comment: In reverse order: $f(x)-\sum c_ix_i$ is the value once you pass to the residue field, ie after modding out by $\mathfrak{m}_x$. Here's how you can observe that the $c_i$ are partial derivatives: take the derivative of $f(x)+c_i(y_i-x_i)+\mathfrak{m}_x^2$. $f(x)$ goes to zero, you get $c_i$ in the direction $y_i$, and anything from $\mathfrak{m}_x^2$ is a product of at least 2 terms that are zero when evaluated at $x$, and therefore has derivative zero when evaluated at $x$.

Comment: I'm trying to make this rigorous. So bear with me please. In $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ I can certainly write $$ f(T)=a(T)+\sum c_i(T)(T_i-x_i)+\mathfrak{m}_x^2 $$ for something in $\mathfrak{m}_x^2$ and $a,c_i \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x}^\ast$. Now by plugging in $x$ on both sides and $x$ into the derivatives i get $a(x)=f(x)$ and $c_i(x)=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial T_i}(x)$. How do you conclude that $a$ and the $c_i$ are constant?

Comment: You're correct, they're not constant, but you evaluate at $x$. That gets you constants.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you mean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41908/discussion-between-kreiser-and-maik-pickl).